# Why VS code not showing function from parent class object in python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, tkinter, parent-child

I have a question about why my child class can't see parents method(it can't see them, but it can use them). I'm creating a GUI in tkinter and I need to use some methods from my parent window.

My parent class look like this:

```
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        manager_of_action = Action_manager()

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (MenuView, LoginView, GameView, ResultView ):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self,action_manager= manager_of_action)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("MenuView")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()
```

and child class look like this:

```
class MenuView(tk.Frame):
    

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, action_manager):
        
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Multiplayer",command=lambda: controller.show_frame("LoginView"),height=3,width=6, bg=("white"), font=controller.title_font)
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Exit",command=lambda: exit(0),height=3,width=6,bg=("white"), font=controller.title_font )
        
        button1.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        button2.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

But VS Code can't see `.title_font()` and `.show_frame()` but if I run my program, it is running as it should. Why it's happening and can I somehow fix it? (If I would have 50 methods in my parent class, I don't want to always look back to parent class and copy + paste my desired fuction.)

Thanks a lot for every help.

EDIT:

VScode doesn't highlight `.title_font()` and `.show_frame()` as it can be seen on picture. This means that VS code is not showing them in IntelliSense (Pylance) menu (. + space menu that will pop up after calling some object). Normally, functions are highlighted in yellow.

[no highlight for .show_frame, .title_font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfAnC.png)

Comment: What do you mean by " VS Code can't see .title_font() and .show_frame()"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I added an image with an example. I hope it clarifies my problem enough.